# In R, how to compare columns of data frames of different sizes

Tags: r, date

I just started working with R so forgive my ignorance.
I have two data sets

1. `ProjectData` which has 20000 rows with a `Date` column containing a list of dates
2. `HolidayData` which has 90 rows with a `Date` column containing a list of Holidays.

I need to compare the dates with `ProjectData` and `HolidayData`, if a date from `ProjectData` is present in `Holiday` then set the `IsHoliday` column in `ProjectData` to `True`.

I thought the code below would work, but it never gives me the right results:

```
for (d in projectdata$cDate)
{
  for (dH in HolidayDate$Date)
  {
    projectdata$IsHoliday <- ifelse(d==dH,TRUE,FALSE)
    break
  }
}
```

Is this approach right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
projectdata$IsHoliday <- projectdata$cDate %in% HolidayDate$Date
```

You have a couple of problems with your code.

Firstly, the loop iterations are a little weird. You are looping through each element of `projectdata$cDate` for each `HolidayDate$Date`, and setting `projectdata$IsHoliday` to be TRUE or FALSE. The problem is you are not saying which element is TRUE or FALSE, so you are setting the while column to true or false each time. You are probably ending up with a column with all TRUE or all FALSE. The `break` is also unnecessary.

Secondly, in general it is good practice to avoid for loops in favor of vectorization in R. A lot of R functions are vectorized - we can call them on a vector (ie a sequence of numbers) and get a sensible output. `%in%` is much better than `==` in this case, as `==` does one by one comparison, whereas `%in%` searches one to all.

Comment: Wow..amazing.that worked!! Thank you so much. Really beginning to appreciate the power of R.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to do

```
library(dplyr)

result =
  HolidayData %>%
  mutate(IsHoliday = TRUE) %>%
  right_join(Project_Data) %>%
  mutate(IsHoliday = IsHoliday %in% TRUE)
```

This has the advantage of getting you a join table with which to do other operations if you want